# How to recover data from deleted dynamic disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I tried to change partition on my dynamic disk in windows 7 and actually deleted entire volume .

Is it possible to recover a data somehow ?

**upd:** a bit more explanation. it was a single HDD with 2  primary partitions, I tried to combine them into one and windows created this as dynamic drive. I wanted to change back and tried another way and selected first simple volume and chose Delete Volume in Disk management utility, but this removed ENTIRE disk. So, now I'm having one big unallocated partition.

Questions:

1. is it possible to fully recover file system (files and folder structure)
2. if not, how to recover data.

Comment: Use any euristic recovering software and recover your data to separate drive/volume. The best way - try to use all soft you find in all regimes, sometimes files not found or repaired with error are successfully recovered by another program or in another regime. PS. Do NOT write to a drive with this removed volume! Do NOT try to recover data or whole volume in-place! It can additionally damage your data.

Comment: is it possible to recovery a file system as is?

Comment: Only if you have made (and checked for consistency) full sector-by-sector (binary, from MBR till the last sector) backup of this drive. If you have a copy, you may do everything you want. If fail you always can restore the initial state of a drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover files from deleted partition](https://superuser.com/questions/178028/recover-files-from-deleted-partition)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recover all data with [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download). It's a really great tool.

So, TestDisk was able to find my last partitions and FS and I copied data via TestDisk to another HDD. Later, I experimented a bit and re-write partitions on the original drive. This returned disk to original state and after `chkdsk` command all files become accessible.